# Sometime Error Using Session With HTML AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

here's my html code

js at index.html

```
 <script>
    function get_session() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://mydomain/getsession.php',
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {

                if (data == "1") {

                    window.location.href = "home.html";

                } else {
                    window.location.href = "login.html";
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error Code: " + jqXHR.status + ", Type:" + textStatus + ", Message: " + errorThrown);

            }
        });

    };
</script>
```

and getsession.php at server-side

```
<?php session_start();  
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
echo "1"; 
else 
echo "0";?>
```

but sometimes isnt working for getsession ..
*im using vps at digital ocean, maybe wrong at my php.ini ??

Comment: Why don't you use GET method of AJAX as you are not posting anything on server

Answer (score 0):

Put your website ip address there and try it

```
http://domain_ip/getsession.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this....

Script

```
<script>
    function get_session() {
        $.ajax({
            dataType:'JSON',
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://mydomain/getsession.php',
            success: function (data) {
                var result=eval(data); 
                if (result.status == true) {

                    window.location.href = "home.html";

                } else 
                  {
                    window.location.href = "login.html";
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error Code: " + jqXHR.status + ", Type:" + textStatus + ", Message: " + errorThrown);

            }
        });

    };
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php session_start();  
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $status = TRUE;
}
else 
{
    $status = FALSE;
}

echo json_encode(array('status'=>$status));
?>
```

Comment: in simulator this is work, but when i build APK , and try at device , always need login..

Answer (score 0):

> PHP code can be -

```
<?php session_start();  
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $status = TRUE;
}
else 
{
    $status = FALSE;
}

echo json_encode(array('status'=>$status));
?>
```

> and ajax code -

```
<script>
    function get_session() 
    {
       $.get('http://mydomain/getsession.ph', function(data) {
        //access data variable here for responce 
       });
    } 
 </script>
```